# State Management(Screen) in Flutter--> Persist Screen

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I continue from the last screen I open in my app after I exited.
Say for example I have screen A, B and C and I was on screen B before I close the application. My question is how do I get to screen B when I reopen the app again.

Comment: as soon as you go to any screen save in preferences something like `lastScreen -> B`; when you start the app check the preference value and work accordingly.

Comment: is it working for your?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I haven't tried it yet, buh i do I save the last screen to preference? please a snippet will help

Comment: @Moplio I am sorry I didn't get that. Please elaborate it.

Comment: What I mean is the last screen I opened, How do I save it (a particular screen )  to shared preference. the snippet u shared helps to get the 'key' of the saved screen and open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` to save the value in `int` for screen A, B and C as  1, 2 and 3 respectively when their `initState()` method fires (to get an idea respective screen is open)

When you open the app next time, you can get the `int` value and use a `switch` to decide what to load.

```
void main() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Widget rootWidget;
  switch (prefs.getInt("key")) {
    case 1:
      rootWidget = Page1();
      break;
    case 2:
      rootWidget = Page2();
      break;
    case 3:
      rootWidget = Page3();
      break;
  }
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: rootWidget));
}
```